# A question regarding the game of 34

Tags: recreational-mathematics

The game of 34 is a two person game using the integers from 1 - 16. Player A selects one of the numbers from 1 - 16. Then player B selects one of the remaining numbers. Players A and B continue to alternate selecting numbers until one of them complete a set of four numbers that sum to 34, thus winning the game. It is my conjecture that player A has a winning advantage by initially selecting 8 or 9. Can anyone help me prove this?

Comment: Player A always wins. I'd post a proof but from your history I see that you never give answers a checkmark.